# Session problem in IE and Google Chrome not in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, session

```
if(empty($_SESSION['count'])){
    $_SESSION['count']=99; 
}else{
   $_SESSION['count']--;
}
echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

In Firefox, I get decremented value but in IE and Chrome it does not decrement the value as well as setting the value. Can anyone tell what's the problem?

Comment: The code itself looks ok; have you verified that the browser security settings for IE and chrome have the proper privacy settings to allow PHP to set a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. Notice that i check for isset($_SESSION['temp']) here, not empty($_SESSION['count']:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['temp'])){
    $_SESSION['temp']=99; 
}else{
   $_SESSION['temp']--;
}
echo $_SESSION['temp'];

?>
```

Comment: @echo "KarghiKeyan" - There is more than that in _iHaveacomputer_'s answer. He/she used isset() instead of empty() and started the session with session_start(). BTW "see and tell me the answer" is not the phrase i would use to get help from anybody...

Comment: it dosn't matter what browser you use for this example, as long as the browser supports cookies - otherwise the session might not work. 

check your webservers temp folder and make sure it writes the session files, and if you session has the "temp" var in it...

Answer (score 0):

PHP code runs on the server, so every browser get's the same result. If it works with one browser but not with others, they have probably different settings. I would check, that all browsers allow setting of a session-cookie, otherwise they will start a new session every time they call your script.

As *iHaveacomputer* already pointed out, the function `empty()` won't work in your example, because it will consider the value 0 as empty and therefore start counting with 99. Use `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` instead.